# Batch FOR space problem

Tags: batch-file

I tried to list all files and directories on a directory by using this format

> dir1:::dir2:::file1:::file2:::

To achieve this, I wrote a batch script. Take a look at it :

```
    @echo off
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET M=
    FOR %%d IN ('dir /B') DO SET M=!M!%%d:::
    ECHO %M%
```

Well, it works for directories/files that doesn't contain spaces, but for those that contained it, it will show just the first word.
For example, suppose the files are "Blue hills.jpg" and "Sunset.jpg".

The expected result is of course

> Blue hills.jpg:::Sunset.jpg:::

But what appears instead is

> Blue:::Sunset.jpg

FYI, I use WinXP. *Is that matter?  I've tried to put quotes in "%%d" but it doesn't work. How can I fix this?
Thanks for the help! And sorry for my bad english, I really have to improve it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your `for` loop for file names containing any text (spaces included) `"tokens=*"`. The `/f` switch is to search for text (filename text).

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET M=
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%d IN ('dir /B') DO SET M=!M!%%d:::

ECHO %M%
```

Works for files and directories with spaces.

If you use `tokens=1` then you get the first word of each file name (using a space as separator). So you would see

```
Blue:::Sunset.jpg:::
```

If you use `tokens=2` then you get the second word:

```
hills.jpg:::
```

Comment: Thanks! My real code does contain the /F parameter, but with your token, the space problem is solved. Could you explain me what is this about? :)

Comment: @Jim: To finalise, if the `tokens` parameter is not specified, like in your original query, `tokens=1` is assumed.

Comment: It will remove all spaces in the front of a filename, to avoid this you could use `delims=` instead of `tokens=*`